# Do smart contract needs a SFT to call esdt_local_mint

Tags: multiversx

My smart contract owns the SFT *HAT-a1a1a1-01*.
The SFT *HAT-a1a1a1-02* also exists but isn't owned by the SC.

When I add local quantity to the SFT with the 02 nonce through a function, my transaction fails with this error:

```
new NFT data on sender
```

Do I need to own the SFT *HAT-a1a1a1-02* to mint it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer in another group:

> Yes, you need to own at least 1 to AddQuantity, since otherwise, you wouldn't have the attributes. When you send an NFT/SFT, if your balance after is 0, the metadata is erased from your account.